# "dnsbackend unable to load module" error when configuring PowerDNS for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dns

I am in need of an easy to setup and free DNS server for Windows XP. I tried [PowerDNS](http://www.powerdns.com/content/home-powerdns.html) but am not able to use the `bind` back-end:

When I put the following in the config file

```
launch=bind
```

I get error

```
dnsbackend unable to load module in bind
```

I am not able to figure out from the documentation what I am doing wrong. `pdns --help=bind` gives me the same error.